# Magento: How to Use for Newbs

Tags: magento

I am new to this software. I was just wondering how to create/edit/check header, side, and footer link. What I have noticed so far from numerous searches is that it requires some type of actual manual programming. And also if it is not a template, I would have to add it through Static Blocks or Edit it through a .phtml/.php/.xml file which I have no idea to do. Assume I have the latest software. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Magento involves actual programming. If you have a piece of code that isn't working correctly we can help you try to figure out why & how to fix it, but we do not offer samples/tutorials nor do we help people find samples/tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shop in english without manual coding at all. But you will get the result you asked for. A hard application without any customisations which probably will not be valid IRS-wise(for example, the invoices in Greece have to contain very specific things. If not they are not valid and you get fined.). The header and the footer are customised by Static Blocks from the backend of Magento without trouble. You will have to search for a documentation of your template ofcourse. There are so many information and we cannot give it to you with just one post. You will have to study and ask the right questions!